# Can I pass a loop as the arguments into a constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I have an array list that contains all the arguments a constructor needs. Referring to each item in the array and then providing the arguments separately seems like a lot of work. I'm wondering whether I can pass each item in the array list by iterating through it inside the brackets of the constructor.

I'm asking if I can do this, or something similar to pass the arguments.

```
constructor object =new constructor(for(String item: parts));
```

parts is the array list here. And all the items in the list are strings.

Comment: Why not pass the entire array in and deal with each value inside the constructor?

Comment: You cannot without using reflection. I would wonder how you ended up in a situation where you have the arguments in a `List` and how you know that they are the right arguments? What happens if the arguements to the ctor change?

Comment: How is that constructor declared?

Comment: No. You can't do that, but you can pass the array list itself and then iterate that in the constructor.

Comment: what is the loop `for(String item: parts)` supposed to do?

Comment: Maybe you can also look into var args? Constructor(String ... items){ //code }

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - it is supposed to auto-map to constructor arguments, and thus allow a uniform initialization, similar to `namedtuple` in Python.

Comment: This can only be achieved using reflection.

Comment: @MCEmperor - nope, not only, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// I have renamed your class "Constructor" to "MyClass", as the former may be confusing

There is no direct syntax in Java for doing this. But with a help of a factory you can achieve something like:

```
final String[] args = {"one", "two", "three"};
final MyClass obj = newMyClass(args); // effect of new Constructor(args[0], args[1], args[2])
final MyClass obj = newMyClass(args[0], args[1], args[2]); // works too, thanks to the variadic declaration syntax
```

For that you will need a factory, either with annotation-processor based code generation, or constructed at the application initialization time  with the help of sun.misc.Unsafe (this is BTW how some high performance serializers do it).

Example:

```
package net.bobah.uf4j;

import org.junit.Test;
import sun.misc.Unsafe;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import static net.bobah.uf4j.MyTest.MyClassFactory.newMyClass;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void runTest() throws Exception {
        final MyClass ctor = newMyClass("one", "two", "three");
        out.println(Arrays.asList(ctor.str1, ctor.str2, ctor.str3));
        // prints [one, two, three]
    }

    public static class MyClass {
        private final String str1;
        private final String str2;
        private final String str3;

        public MyClass(String str1, String str2, String str3) {
            this.str1 = str1;
            this.str2 = str2;
            this.str3 = str3;
        }

    }

    public static class MyClassFactory {
        private static Unsafe getUnsafe() {
            try {
                Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                return (Unsafe) f.get(null);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException cause) {
                throw new RuntimeException(cause);
            }
        }

        private static final Unsafe unsafe = getUnsafe();

        private static final List<BiConsumer<MyClass, String>> fieldInitializers = new ArrayList<>();

        static {
            // this can be extended to support one-to-many mappings from args to fields, or to do type transformation on the way
            for (Field field : MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
                if (String.class.equals(field.getType())) {
                    final long offset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(field);
                    fieldInitializers.add((obj, val) -> {
                        unsafe.putObject(obj, offset, val);
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        public static MyClass newMyClass(String... args) throws InstantiationException {
            assert args.length == fieldInitializers.size();

            // create uninitialized instance
            final MyClass obj = (MyClass) unsafe.allocateInstance(MyClass.class);

            // inject final fields
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
                fieldInitializers.get(i).accept(obj, args[i]);
            }

            return obj;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The person who asked the question is probably not proficient with many of the features used here (reflection, lambdas, Unsafe, ...), so this does not seem helpful (I did not downvote)

Comment: None of these features are “rocket science”. They are just tools. The OP has asked a question about a rather advanced syntax (intentionally or not). What makes you think (s)he is not capable of comprehending the answer?

Comment: The syntax in the question (passing a loop as an argument) does not make sense (whats the result of a loop? usually `void`). Someone who knows how to use reflection, lambdas, generics and other "advanced" language features is already way past the point where they think you can pass a loop as an argument. They may still be able to proficiently use these concepts, but the solution is probably way simpler than that.

Comment: To correctly answer a question it is not as important to see what is asked as _why_ it is asked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `constructor` is declared like this:

```
public contructor(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4)
```

Your idea is not the right way to approach this. What if `parts` does not have exactly 4 elements? What you want is an overloaded constructor that takes the entire list:

```
public constructor(List<String> strings)
{
    this(strings.get(0), strings.get(1), strings.get(2), strings.get(3));
}
```

This way, you can call the constructor in many different places with different lists, but you only have to "deconstruct" the list in one place (the overloaded constructor). E.g.:

```
constructor a = new constructor(list1);
constructor b = new constructor(parts);

constructor c1 = new constructor(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4");
// same as:
constructor c2 = new constructor("1", "2", "3", "4");
```

Note that the example only works with at least 4 elements in the list:

```
constructor e1 = new constructor(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar")); // will error
constructor e2 = new constructor(Collections.emptyList()); // will error
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me as if you are looking for something that in other programming languages, e.g. Groovy, is referred to as **coercion**, i.e.of lists into the desired types.

**This is not possible in Java up to version 10**, but who knows what the future will bring.

Answer (score -1):

Your question brings more question than answers: if you have an array or list of String, then have your constructor take that arrays/list.

If you need to convert the content of this array/list into more of your object, your answer is `Stream`, you need not complex thing like reflection:

```
String[] myArray = ...;
MyType[] a = Arrays.stream(myArray).map(MyType::new).toArray(MyType[]::new);

Collection<String> coll = ...;
List<MyType> b = coll.stream().map(MyType::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could certainly do more: if you have a constructor whose arity is 3 (example: 3 String):

- We first create a stream of [0, size() / arity] which is the number of object you'll need to construct. Multiply it arity and you get the index of the first item to pass to your constructor.
- We map the `index` to `MyObj`: the `safeGet` take care of extracting the value form the list (it would work with an array too but you'll simply need it to use `length` and `[]` instead).
- `MyObj` have a constructor taking each of your tuple. If the constructor needs to convert one of the source object (String) into another (for example, integer), then you would probably be best to use a static method valueOf doing the String to object.
- From the `Stream`, we return array but you may use `collect(toList())` for a List.

Here is a first example:

```
  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");
    // fails if list.size() is not multiple of 3
    final int arity = 3;
    final MyObj[] myObj = IntStream.range(0, list.size() / arity).map(n -> arity * n)
    .mapToObj(index -> new MyObj(safeGet(list, index, 0), safeGet(list, index, 1), safeGet(list, index, 2)))
    .toArray(MyObj[]::new)
    ;

  }

  private static <T> T safeGet(final List<T> list, final int baseIndex, final int relativeIndex) {
    final int index = baseIndex + relativeIndex;
    return index < list.size() ? list.get(index) : null;
  }

  static class MyObj {
    public MyObj(final String a, final String b, final String c) {
    }
  }
```

Here a second example, with a constructor accepting an `int` rather than a `String`:

```
  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "0", "C", "D", "2", "F");
    // fails if list.size() is not multiple of 3
    final int arity = 3;
    final MyObj[] myObj = IntStream.range(0, list.size() / arity).map(n -> arity * n)
        .mapToObj(index -> MyObj.valueOf(list, index))
        .toArray(MyObj[]::new)
        ;

    Arrays.stream(myObj).forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  private static <T> T safeGet(final List<T> list, final int baseIndex, final int relativeIndex) {
    final int index = baseIndex + relativeIndex;
    return index < list.size() ? list.get(index) : null;
  }

  static class MyObj {
    public MyObj(final String a, final int b, final String c) {
    }

    public static MyObj valueOf(final List<String> source, final int baseIndex) {
      final String a = safeGet(source, baseIndex, 0);
      final int b = Integer.parseInt(safeGet(source, baseIndex, 1));
      final String c = safeGet(source, baseIndex, 2);
      return new MyObj(a, b, c);

    }

  }
```